# How does "classnames" work when there are multiple classes with same name

Tags: html, css, typescript

I am reading some code where it is using npm utility **classnames** from https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames.

In the scss file, it has multiple classes with the same name (small and large) like below:

```
.buttonA {
  &.small {
    height: 50px;
  }
  &.large {
    height: 80px;
  }
}

.buttonB {
  &.small {
    height: 20px;
  }
  &.large {
    height: 40px;
  }
}
```

This is the tsx file:

```
<IconButton
  ....
  className={
    classNames('buttonA', 'small')
  }
/>
```

This confused me a lot as I am not sure which 'small' class it will choose to use, since we have 2 of them in scss. I suppose it would choose the 'small' class from buttonA, because it specifies buttonA as the first parameter? but that makes me wondering if these parameter are depend on each other? What if I do classNames('buttonB', 'small'), or, simply  classNames('small')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the problem here is that you are overestimating what it is that `classnames` does and perhaps misunderstanding how CSS and/or Sass work.

`classnames` is simply a means of dynamically and conditionally concatenating strings.  That's *all* it is doing-- it isn't interrogating and understanding any CSS that may be being applied to the `className` string values it is outputting.  You don't even have to use it for `className` string values-- you could use it for other things like conditionally pluralizing messaging, like

```
const errors = ['this is required', 'that is also required'];
const numErrs = errors.length;
const errMsg = `You have ${numErrs} ${classnames('error', { s: numErrs > 1 })}`;

// errMsg is "You have 1 error" for a single error and "You have 2 errors" for two errors
```

Your Sass file is using the [parent selector (`&`)](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector) to concatenate the inner rules to the parent container to create the following CSS output:

```css
.buttonA.small {
  /* properties here will applied to an element with both `buttonA` and `small` class */
  height: 50px;
}

.buttonA.large {
  /* properties here will applied to an element with both `buttonA` and `large` class */
  height: 80px;
}

.buttonB.small {
  /* properties here will applied to an element with both `buttonB` and `small` class */
  height: 20px;
}

.buttonB.large {
  /* properties here will applied to an element with both `buttonB` and `large` class */
  height: 40px;
}
```

SO-- with these two concepts in mind:

1. Your `classnames('buttonA', 'small')` will output the string `"buttonA small"`, meaning that the element for which they are set as the `className` value will have the classes `.buttonA` and `.small`
2. Understanding how the Sass file outputs CSS and how that CSS will be applied in the browser, the element will have a `height` of `50px`

Comment: Ah...That makes a lot of sense!!! Really appreciate your help ! So if we have something like classNames('small'), then there will be no matching css found and hence no height would be applied, right?

Comment: Also, I think the order of the elements in classNames doesn't matter? For example,  classNames('small', 'buttonA') will still set height to be 50px?

Comment: You are correct on both accounts-- for the `.small` class alone there is no matching CSS selector in the Sass you have shown, so no styles will be applied from that Sass; and order is unimportant for CSS selectors.  Hope this has helped-- happy coding!